# Truck 24V->12V DC regulator gets me 13.5 volts, how can I get it to 12.0 +- 0.5?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am wondering whether I need a new regulator or is there something that can fix my issue. BTW, what's the deal with 24->12V regulators that all output 13.5V volts? I have quite sensitive IT networking equipment which can't handle anything above 13V.

Comment: All of them don't so it's not a deal really but if you have one that does then show the circuit.

Comment: Have you checked the voltage from your regulator when it is driving a load? Some regulators are a higher voltage when unloaded because they are not perfect voltage supplies. Try drawing a few hundred mA, ideally comparable to your equipment, and then measure the voltage.

Comment: 13.5 V is probably because this a perfectly normal voltage for a car cigarette lighter output (nominally 12 V) which has a large output voltage range depending on the condition of the battery and engine. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cigarette_lighter_receptacle#Design_considerations)

Comment: I need 2-2.5A. Thank you everyone for your valuable input. I will upvote as soon as I have the points!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13.8V is the normal voltage in an automotive "12V" electrical system when the motor (and thus alternator) is in action.

You can get or make something that actually outputs 12V, or perhaps use an [LM1117](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117-n.pdf) and a couple resistors (or similar LDO) to drop the voltage a bit. The worst-case dropout voltage (low Ta, 800mA out) is 1.4V so it's just good enough.

[image]

With no heatsink, maybe 300-400mA per regulator (depending on high ambient can get) with a decent heatsink, the full 800mA should be no problem. You might want to add the diode from out to in, and do pay attention to the output capacitor requirements or it will oscillate like a banshee. You have been warned.

This combination of a switching regulator followed by an LDO is SOP when a low-noise high-performance power supply is required. Probably quite unnecessary for your stuff- and if it was used for this purpose you'd probably want a bit more headroom.

Comment: Where are you getting his current requirements from?

Comment: @ACD Nowhere, and his question is not specific about current, just implied that it's not enormous because it's IT equipment. I'm telling Sven **what a single regulator is capable of**. It's up to him to check whether one (with or without heatsink) is adequate or whether the loads could be split to use multiple regulators.

Comment: oh okay. I was just wondering because I was going to pick out a module for him but gave up once I didn't know the current needed. Thought I missed it in a comment or something.

Answer (score 0):

13.5 volts is standard automotive bus voltage. Real 12v won't charge the battery.

Pretty much anything automotive that says "12v" is going to be decently above that voltage, but on the flip side will handle a very noisy power supply.

If you need proper 12v just inline something like an LM2937ET-12. If it's in a vehicle also include a coil and capacitor, ideally each the size of a soda can.

Comment: LM7812 needs **15 V** at the input to work properly.

Comment: Agreed, this is a terrible suggestion - LM7812 and similar linear regulators have a huge drop-out voltage.

Comment: @KyranF if either of you two geniuses have a better component in mind....

Comment: Okay then :) A "better" one would be the Texas Instruments LM2937ET-12, which has only 500mV dropout so even at 12V nominal this still fits within the OP's +-0.5V requirement. Only 0.5A output though. Basically with automotive you either design for the rough high voltage issue, or you run stuff at a nice low 5V or less, through some nice DC-DC converters with heavy filtering to deal with the poor load/line issues.

Comment: @KyranF didn't know about that one. Updated.

Comment: I have removed the down-vote, for your sake.

Answer (score 0):

What 24V-12V regulator are you using? Is it adjustable so that you could set it to 12.0V exactly?

If not you need a new regulator to go from 24V - 12V that is more accurate. What are your current requirements? Many of these modules exist. Lookup DC/DC buck converters/modules and choose one that can handle the current requirements of your system.

BTW, some 24V - 12V regulators used in lead acid battery applications go to 13.5V nominally because that is a common voltage to charge 12V car batteries at.

Comment: not ajustable, it feels really cheap.

Comment: But it turns out it was quite expensive :)